# MFC: Using CHtmlView with memory string via about: or data:?

Tags: html, mfc, uri

I am trying out `CHtmlView` to display html from memory variables.  After having dealt with the various exceptions you get in debug mode, have it working for very small strings via the `about:` uri.

Example:

```
Navigate(_T("about:<html><head></head><body>Hello</body></html>"))
```

works for small items but not larger strings.   Does anyone know the documented limitation for `about:` ?

Now I found a new item that supposed to be available for IE, the `data:` entry, but when I try

```
Navigate(_T("data:text/html, <html><head></head><body>Hello</body></html>"))
```

It doesn't work, comes up with the fancy *webpage can't be displayed* page.   Does anyone know why `CHtmlView` doesn't support `data:` and if there is any other trick that can be used to use memory variable data for html display in `CHtmlView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option for setting HTML content directly, is to read from memory using `IStream`

MFC's `CHtmlEditCtrl` uses a similar method to set document html content, except MFC uses `CStreamOnCString`.

You may need to set the content to UTF8 for compatibility. To use UTF8, 
change `CString` to `CStringA` in the code below, and pass UTF8 string to the function `SetHTMLContent(htmlview, u8"<html>...")`

```
HRESULT SetHTMLContent(CHtmlView* htmlview, CString html)
{
    if(!html.GetLength()) return E_FAIL;

    CComPtr<IDispatch> disp = htmlview->GetHtmlDocument();
    if(!disp)
    {
        //not initialized, try again
        htmlview->Navigate(_T("about:"));
        disp = htmlview->GetHtmlDocument();
        if(!disp)
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument2> doc2 = disp;
    if(!doc2) return E_NOINTERFACE;

    int charsize = sizeof(html.GetAt(0));
    IStream *istream = SHCreateMemStream(
        reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(html.GetBuffer()), charsize * html.GetLength());
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    if(istream)
    {
        CComQIPtr<IPersistStreamInit> psi = doc2;
        if(psi)
            hr = psi->Load(istream);
        istream->Release();
    }
    html.ReleaseBuffer();

    return hr;
}
```

Usage:

```
CString str = _T("<html><head></head><body>Hello</body></html>");
SetHTMLContent(m_chtmlview, str);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the URL when right click / properties to show up.  I tried CComBSTR bstrurl(_T("https://www.testit.none"));  doc2->put_URL(bstrurl); but it remains about:blank.  Also won't doc2 leak if SHCreateMemStream fails?

Comment: That's interesting. `IHTMLDocument2::put_URL` does same thing as `SetHTMLContent`, although I can't find any documentation for it. Otherwise it's the answer to your original question! It won't change the address. About leaks, there is no leak in above function. I added another error check after `QueryInterface`.

Comment: How about doc2 if istream is NULL?  It never gets assigned to the smart pointer.

Comment: No, there is no leak. I added another `hr = E_FAIL` so if `SHCreateMemStream` then the function returns `E_FAIL`.

Comment: So no `doc2->Release()` is needed when `SHCreateMemStream` fails?

Comment: I see what you mean. I changed everything to `CComXXX` to avoid leaks.